# How does the maintenance cost of turboprops compare to turbofans?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, engine, turboprop, geared-turbofan

I was initially under the impression that the added complexity of gearing in a turboprop would lead to more maintenance. Then I found out geared turbofans are becoming fairly common so there should be no difference in maintenance on that account.

I also thought the bypass air would play a role in cooling the casing for the combustion chamber onwards, but maybe this isn't a relevant factor.

Does anyone know how the maintenance cost of these two types of engines compare?